# Destroy Hierarchy of directory?

Tags: bash

I have a folder with many folders in it and many folders below that and so on and so forth. In those final folders are are small clusters of files. I am attempting to move those files to the main folder and delete the now empty folder hierarchy. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=`whoami`
DEST="/Users/"$NAME"/Desktop/Music 2"
FILES=`find "$DEST" -type f`
for F in "$FILES"
    do
        mv "${F}" "${DEST}"
    done
```

If I replace the `mv` command with "echo" it will catch all the right names but when I run this it gives me an error saying that the name is too long. Help will be greatly appreciated.

So say I have

```
 /foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
 /foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
 /foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
```

I want `test1.txt`, `test2.doc`, and `test3.mp3` to be in `/foo`, and for each of the (now empty) directories `/foo/bar`, `/foo/bar/in`, `/foo/bar/in/side`, `/foo/bar/in/down`, `/foo/bar/last`, and `/foo/bar/last/dog` to be deleted.

End result:

```
 /foo/test1.txt
 /foo/test2.doc
 /foo/test3.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
find "$DEST" -type f -exec bash -c '
    mv "$1" "$DEST"; rmdir "${1%/*}" &>/dev/null
' -- {} \;
```

Comment: put that in place of the mv command? or for the whole "for" command?

Comment: ok i tried it and that destroys the hierarchy but it also deletes the files that the folders at the end have.

Comment: That's a `rmdir` per file; a tad expensive if done very often. Once off, for a few (thousand) files, it won't matter, but for production work, not entirely satisfactory.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

DEST="/Users/Zelon/Desktop/Music 2"

FILES=`find "$DEST" -type f`

for F in "$FILES"

    do

        find "$DEST" -type f -exec bash -c '

     rm -f "$1"; rmdir "${1%/*}" &>/dev/null

' -- {} \;

    done

Answer (score 0):

Especially when the path names have spaces in them, using `FILES=$(find ...)` really doesn't work.  You got the file name too long message because `"$FILES"` in the for loop treats all the names as a single file name; `${F}` contains everything, and the `mv` command is trying to move a single file to `${DEST}`.

The [`rmdir -p`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rmdir.html) command removes directories that are empty (think of `-p` for 'prune'), working depth first.

GNU `mv` has a very useful option `-t target` for use in this context:

```
DEST=/foo
find /foo/bar -type f -exec mv -t "${DEST}" {} +
find /foo/bar -type d -depth -exec rmdir -p {} +
```

Given that you're on Mac OS X, you don't have quite that convenience, so your best bet is a slower (but equally effective):

```
DEST=/foo
find /foo/bar -type f -exec mv {} "${DEST}" ';'
find /foo/bar -type d -depth -exec rmdir -p {} +
```

This executes the `mv` command once per file (whereas with GNU `mv`, many files may be moved with a single invocation).  Otherwise, it is equivalent.

Both sets of commands avoid the issues with spaces in file names.

Note that if `$DEST` is the same as the directory you're searching in, you'll run into problems moving the files already in `$DEST` over themselves.  As written, the code does not avoid that problem.  If necessary, you can avoid that with:

```
find "$DEST"/*/ -type f ...
```

The trailing slash enforces 'only directories' (think of it as equivalent to `"$DEST"/*/.`).

---

#### Proof of concept script

Remember: always test destructive scripts (scripts that delete stuff) on *copies* of the live material, unless you've got good backups on hand.  Actually, make them on copies anyway; it is almost invariably quicker to make a copy than to recover from a backup (but you should have a backup anyway if the data is crucial).

```
echo "Before"
du -a .

filelist="./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
          ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
          ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3"
for file in $filelist
do
    mkdir -p $(dirname $file)
    cp script $file
done

FIFO=./foo/bar/first/installment
mkdir $(dirname $FIFO)
mkfifo $FIFO

echo "Created"
du -a .

echo "Clean up"
DEST=./foo
find ./foo/bar -type f -exec mv {} "${DEST}" ';'
find ./foo/bar -depth -type d -exec rmdir -p {} + 2>/dev/null

echo "After"
du -a .

rm -fr ./foo
```

The `rmdir -p` process is noisy.  It reports on directories it can't remove. The GNU version of `rmdir` provides an option to suppress some errors (`--ignore-fail-on-non-empty`), but in the context, you end up with some errors about non-existent directories, too (they were removed by the pruning process before the entry that listed the directory on its own).  So, after putting up with the noise for a bit, I redirected all errors from `rmdir` to `/dev/null`.  Remove that redirection until you're satisfied things work as intended.

This script should be run in an empty directory you've just created and made your current directory:

```
mkdir junk
cd junk
cp ../script .
sh -x ./script
```

Sample output:

```
$ sh -x script
+ echo Before
Before
+ du -a .
4   ./script
8   .
+ filelist='./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
          ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
          ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3'
+ for file in '$filelist'
++ dirname ./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
+ mkdir -p ./foo/bar/in/side
+ cp script ./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
+ for file in '$filelist'
++ dirname ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
+ mkdir -p ./foo/bar/in/down
+ cp script ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
+ for file in '$filelist'
++ dirname ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
+ mkdir -p ./foo/bar/last/dog
+ cp script ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
+ FIFO=./foo/bar/first/installment
++ dirname ./foo/bar/first/installment
+ mkdir ./foo/bar/first
+ mkfifo ./foo/bar/first/installment
+ echo Created
Created
+ du -a .
4   ./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
8   ./foo/bar/in/side
4   ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
8   ./foo/bar/in/down
20  ./foo/bar/in
4   ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
8   ./foo/bar/last/dog
12  ./foo/bar/last
0   ./foo/bar/first/installment
4   ./foo/bar/first
40  ./foo/bar
44  ./foo
4   ./script
52  .
+ echo 'Clean up'
Clean up
+ DEST=./foo
+ find ./foo/bar -type f -exec mv '{}' ./foo ';'
+ find ./foo/bar -depth -type d -exec rmdir -p '{}' +
+ echo After
After
+ du -a .
0   ./foo/bar/first/installment
4   ./foo/bar/first
8   ./foo/bar
4   ./foo/test1.txt
4   ./foo/test3.mp3
4   ./foo/test2.doc
24  ./foo
4   ./script
32  .
+ rm -fr ./foo
```

Note that this script carefully creates a non-file (a FIFO) in a separate directory under `./foo/bar` and shows that it is left behind.  Comment out the `mkfifo` line that create the FIFO and the run looks like:

```
$ sh -x script
+ echo Before
Before
+ du -a .
4   ./script
8   .
+ filelist='./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
          ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
          ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3'
+ for file in '$filelist'
++ dirname ./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
+ mkdir -p ./foo/bar/in/side
+ cp script ./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
+ for file in '$filelist'
++ dirname ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
+ mkdir -p ./foo/bar/in/down
+ cp script ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
+ for file in '$filelist'
++ dirname ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
+ mkdir -p ./foo/bar/last/dog
+ cp script ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
+ FIFO=./foo/bar/first/installment
++ dirname ./foo/bar/first/installment
+ mkdir ./foo/bar/first
+ echo Created
Created
+ du -a .
4   ./foo/bar/in/side/test1.txt
8   ./foo/bar/in/side
4   ./foo/bar/in/down/test2.doc
8   ./foo/bar/in/down
20  ./foo/bar/in
4   ./foo/bar/last/dog/test3.mp3
8   ./foo/bar/last/dog
12  ./foo/bar/last
4   ./foo/bar/first
40  ./foo/bar
44  ./foo
4   ./script
52  .
+ echo 'Clean up'
Clean up
+ DEST=./foo
+ find ./foo/bar -type f -exec mv '{}' ./foo ';'
+ find ./foo/bar -depth -type d -exec rmdir -p '{}' +
+ echo After
After
+ du -a .
4   ./foo/test1.txt
4   ./foo/test3.mp3
4   ./foo/test2.doc
16  ./foo
4   ./script
24  .
+ rm -fr ./foo
$
```

This strongly suggests that if written properly and handled carefully, the code above does work correctly without damaging the system.  But you should still be cautious before using any variant of this in production (and even in test).

Tests run on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative.

Comment: the $DEST directory is where i'm moving them, will the code "DEST=/foo
find /foo/bar -type f -exec mv {} "${DEST}" ';'
find /foo/bar -type d -depth -exec rmdir -p {} +" move them to that location?

Comment: Yes; the move commands move the files to `${DEST}`.  Since there will be files in `$DEST`, it won't matter when `rmdir` looks to prune the directory; it will not be deleted.

Comment: You don't ever test on live directories, do you?  You always test remove operations on copies first, don't you?  Or, if you didn't before, you will in future.  It worked for me.  I'll double check, but ...

Comment: sorry i see the issue i messed up when editing the code for my parameters. its ok though i was able to recover the applications off of a previous backup and fixed the script i messed up. it will take a bit before i can run it again. it might have destroyed files system wide.

Comment: You have to be excruciatingly careful with any destructive script.  Doubly so when you didn't write and test every line of it.  I'm relieved that you have backups to work from; I'm sorry that I didn't warn you to take precautions. Note that the code will not preserve both `/foo/bar/in/file9.txt` and `/foo/bar/last/file9.txt` -- it will only keep one and it is quasi-arbitrary which one is kept. You might be able to modify it handle name collisions, but it won't be completely straight-forward.